# Simple and persistent CGI interface

Tags: apache, cgi

I like the simplicity of CGI with Apache, but would like to be able to just leave my code running between CGI requests.  mod_perl keeps coming up in this context, except that I'm not writing in Perl.

I'm aware of FastCGI, but am looking for something much simpler - something that doesn't involve networking or libraries in the CGI program itself.  I'm thinking something that still uses stdin and stdout, but with a few special things to signal the end of one request, and another thing to start and give the parameters for a new request.

It seems obvious enough that you'd think its out there somewhere, but I wouldn't know how to find it.  Anybody aware of such a thing?

Comment: Get libraries for FastCGI, and it is very simple.

Comment: Like I said, I wanted to avoid something as complex as FastCGI

Answer (score 0):

Use a script-based mini web server such as:

- [shell httpd](http://www.dartmouth.edu/%7Erc/classes/ksh/sh-httpd.html)
- [micro_httpd](http://www.acme.com/software/micro_httpd/),
- [Micro-HTTPD](https://github.com/nmmmnu/Micro-HTTPD)
- [xs-httpd](http://www.xs-httpd.org/)
- [webfs](http://homes.cs.washington.edu/%7Etom/pubs/webfs.html)

  or [something](https://wiki.debian.org/WebServers) [similar](http://www.acme.com/).